"How to determine the conditions for a polynomial to always be positive?
I have a polynomial of the type p(x)=a0+a1x+a2x^2+a3x^3+ ... +a6x^6, I want conditions so that p(x) is always positive, knowing that x> or = 0.
How can I implement this in wolfran in order to put conditions on the a_i coefficients?
specifically, I need x[a10 a11 + (a10 a12 + a10 b12) x + (a11 a12 + a10 a13 + a11 b12 +
a10 b13) x^2 + (a11 a13 + a12 b12 + a11 b13 ) x^3 + (a13 b12 +
a12 b13) x^4 + (a13 b13) x^5]  to always be positive with x > or = 0.

Since $x$ is a factor, then when $x=0$ the expression evaluates to $0$ which is not positive.

Without restriction of generality, we can assume that $a_6=1$ (if not, just divide the whole polynomial by $a_6$). Thus f[x_] = a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4 + a5 x^5 + x^6 and then you can ask Mathematica to Resolve[ForAll[x, x >= 0, f[x] > 0], Reals] which seems to take a long time and will probably generate a very large number of conditions.

Could be slow...ee = a10 a11 + (a10 a12 + a10 b12) x + (a11 a12 + a10 a13 + a11 b12 +       a10 b13) x^2 + (a11 a13 + a12 b12 + a11 b13) x^3 + (a13 b12 +       a12 b13) x^4 + (a13 b13) x^5; Resolve[  ForAll[x, x > 0, ee > 0], {a10, a11, a12, b12, a13, b13}]

This is rather math than Mathematica question. A sufficient condition is a10 a11 + (a10 a12 + a10 b12) x + (a11 a12 + a10 a13 + a11 b12 +       a10 b13) x^2 + (a11 a13 + a12 b12 + a11 b13) x^3 + (a13 b12 +       a12 b13) x^4 + (a13 b13) x^5 to be a Hurwitz polynomial. The necessary condition to this end is derived by Reduce[a10 a11 > 0 && a10 a12 + a10 b12 > 0 &&    a11 a12 + a10 a13 + a11 b12 + a10 b13 > 0 &&    a11 a13 + a12 b12 + a11 b13 > 0 && a11 a13 + a12 b12 + a11 b13 > 0 &&    a13 b13 > 0, Reals].

The above results in (b13 < 0 &&     a13 < 0 && ((b12 <          0 && ((a12 <= 0 && a11 < 0 && a10 < 0) || (0 < a12 < -b12 &&             a11 < -((a12 b12)/(a13 + b13)) && a10 < 0))) || (b12 >=          0 && ((a12 < -b12 && a11 < -((a12 b12)/(a13 + b13)) &&             a10 < 0) || (a12 > 0 &&             0 < a11 < -((a12 b12)/(a13 + b13)) &&             0 < a10 < (-a11 a12 - a11 b12)/(a13 + b13)))))) || (b13 >   0 && a13 >   0 && ((b12 <=   0 &&

((a12 < 0 && -((a12 b12)/(a13 + b13)) < a11 <  0 && (-a11 a12 - a11 b12)/(a13 + b13) < a10 <   0) || (a12 > -b12 && a11 > -((a12 b12)/(a13 + b13)) &&   a10 > 0))) || (b12 >          0 && ((-b12 < a12 <= 0 && a11 > -((a12 b12)/(a13 + b13)) &&  a10 > 0) || (a12 > 0 && a11 > 0 && a10 > 0))))).

You may looking at the zeros of the polynomial. For x>=0 and p[x]>0 we need to request that the largest real zero is <0.
In addition we also to need request that p[x]>0, otherwise there is no solution.
Here is an example:
SeedRandom[1];
pn[x_] = Sum[RandomReal[{-1, 1}] (x + 11)^i, {i, 0, 6}];
Roots[pn[x] == 0, x]

x == -11.866 - 0.921706 I || x == -11.866 + 0.921706 I || 
 x == -10.7724 - 0.77693 I || x == -10.7724 + 0.77693 I || 
 x == -10.3425 || x == -0.101538

and pn[0]:
pn[0]

1466.13

A plot confirms that p[x]>0 for x>=0:
Plot[pn[x], {x, 0, 5}]

